# How to group by multiple rows and column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

1. For each user 3 codes are there(10,20,30)
2. if all codes(10,20,30) are true then it has to JOINED
3. if any codes(10,20,30) are False then it has to NEGLECTED
4. WE have to check max(date)

Table is below:

```
+-------+------+-------+------------+
| user  | code | bool  |    date    |
+-------+------+-------+------------+
| user1 |  10  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user1 |  20  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user1 |  30  | False | 31/10/2019 |
| user2 |  10  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user2 |  20  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user2 |  30  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user3 |  10  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user3 |  20  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
| user3 |  30  | True  | 31/10/2019 |
+-------+------+-------+------------+
```

Output user2 and user3 is JOINED, user1 is NEGLECTED

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
|    DATE    | JOINED | NEGLECTED |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 31/10/2019 |    2   |    1      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: user3 is false,true,true so how is this joined?

Comment: @P.Salmon, my bad, changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the column `bool` is of data type `BOOL`, so you can do it in 2 levels of aggregation:

```
select t.date,
  sum(total = 3) joined,
  sum(total <> 3) neglected
from (
  select date, user, sum(bool) total
  from tablename
  group by date, user
) t
group by t.date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ep3JwyR3bwXMzzVQ8tgNu/1).
Results:

```
| date       | joined | neglected |
| ---------- | ------ | --------- |
| 31/10/2019 | 2      | 1         |
```

If the column's `bool` data type is `VARCHAR` then change:

```
sum(bool) total
```

to:

```
sum(bool = 'True') total
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a query that groups the users and calculates their status based on the codes. Then, I'd wrap this query with an aggregate query to count the number of users joined or neglected each day:

```sql
SELECT   `date`,
         SUM(`status` = 'joined') AS joined,
         SUM(`status` = 'neglected') AS neglected
FROM     (SELECT   `user`,
                   `date`,
                   CASE BIT_AND(bool) WHEN TRUE THEN 'joined' ELSE 'neglected' END AS status
          FROM     `mytable`
          GROUP BY `user`, `date`) t
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: BITWISE_AND is not a mysql function.

Comment: @P.Salmon arg, I meant `bit_and` - edited and fixed. Thanks for noticing!